# Bing translator widget doesn't remember that translation is enabled

Tags: html, localization, bing, bing-api

I'm considering using the  [Bing Translator Widget](http://www.bing.com/widget/translator) on my site. In it's default state, the widget remembers you want the page translated into a particular language from page to page.  However as soon as I try and do any customisation (eg by calling the Translate function manually when a flag image is clicked) that particular function breaks and it no longer remembers the selected language from page to page.

Is there any way to use this translator with custom buttons, while also retaining the function for it to remember the selected translation?

I've tried to do this by simply hiding the default UI in CSS but I can't seem to find any CSS to hide the grey "Translate" button.

I want to call translate manually this:

```
Microsoft.Translator.Widget.Translate('en', languageCode, onProgress, onError, onComplete, onRestoreOriginal, 8000);
```

..but this stops the page-to-page translation working :(